# creating a dynamically named object

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a dynamically named object.

something like

```
private var myVar:String = "dynamicName";
private var [myVar+"staticName"]:Object = new Object;
```

but what i wrote above dosn't work for some reason.

Comment: Why the hell would you want that?

Comment: You can't do that. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: i need a dynamic name for that object, since its a network shared object.
every network user has such an object, but there are no correspondent objects allowed. so i want to use the username as a part of the object name to prevent correspondens.

Comment: Does the object even keep its name when you "share" it? I would have thought just the data is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if you get that to work.

Better to save your dynamically created objects in an array or possibly a Dictionary.  The Flex Framework uses Arrays for itemRenderers in list based classes, for example.  Try something like this using a Dictionary:

```
private var myObjects : Dictionary = new Dictionary()
```

In some method where you create the children:

```
private var myVar:String = "dynamicName";
myObjects[myVar+"staticName"] = new Object();
```

Comment: tried that, getting the error:

1078: Label has to be a simple identifier.

Comment: remove the :Object from after myObjects[myVar+"staticName"] so that it reads myObjects[myVar+"staticName"] = new Object();

Comment: Thanks to HeavilyInvoled for catching the typo in my source code.  Glad we were able to help @masi

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var myDynamicObjects:Object = new Object();
var myVar:String = "dynamicName";
myDynamicObjects[myVar + "staticName"] = new Object();
```

Using square brackets allows you to manipulate dynamic object properties.

== Edit ==

Better yet, like @www.Flextras.com says, use a dictionary or an array.